# It's possible with a non-blocking SocketChannel to read all present buffered data while preventing further receiving from clients?

Tags: java, sockets, nio, nonblocking, socketchannel

The use case is, in an only reading server, when a shutdown request is received to prevent clients to send more data but do the best effort to process possible data in buffers.

I've tried with `shutdownInput()` and `socket.close()`, which successfully prevent further reading but also buffered content.

`shutdownInput()` was my first bet, but documentation clearly says that further `read()` will return -1, althought I've seen some code [in Apache NIFI](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/aa741cc5967f62c3c38c2a47e712b7faa6fe19ff/nifi-commons/nifi-utils/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/remote/io/socket/SocketChannelInputStream.java#L54) that seems to read data after shutdown.

Comment: you must think of the code fragment "asynchronous"!? (the `do` executes simultaneously to "shutdown", but in any case (only) `while (bytesRead > 0)`)

Comment: Every time you do a read you are removing data from the socket receive buffer, which makes it possible for the sender to send more data. The answer here is `shutdownInput()`, at least in theory, but in practice there are at least three separate behaviours, two of which are not what you want.